Prove from the definition that $z_n \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$
Let $$z_n = \frac{n^2 + 2 + 3in}{2n^2 - n} ~~~~~~ \text{for } n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\left| z_n - \frac{1}{2} \right|
&= \left| \frac{n^2 + 2 + 3in}{2n^2 - n} - \frac{1}{2} \right|\\
&= \left| \frac{2n^2 + 4 + 6in - 2n^2 + n}{4n^2 - 2n} \right|\\
&= \left| \frac{4 + n + 6in}{4n^2 - 2n} \right|\\
&\overset{?}= \sqrt{\frac{4^2 + n^2 + (6in)^2}{4n^2 - 2n}}\\
&\overset{?}= \sqrt{\frac{4^2 + n^2 + 36(-1)n^2}{4n^2 - 2n}}\\
&\overset{?}= \sqrt{\frac{4^2 - 35n^2}{4n^2 - 2n}}
\end{align*}
For a fixed $\epsilon >0$ my aim is to find an index $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that when $n > N$ then the distance $\left| z_n - \frac{1}{2} \right| < \epsilon$. I have the structure ready to prove this but it obviously relies on the calculation above and I am not sure my algebra (particularly the removal of the complex modulus) is correct and even if it is correct I'm not sure how best to simplify/bound it?

The absolute value of $a+ib$ is $\sqrt{a^2 +b^2}$. Your expression is entirely wrong. Start by separating the real and imaginary parts.

Yes. It is enough to consider the numerator since the denominator is a positive integer for each $n$.

Sorry I deleted my comment @Gary, I was saying even knowing the definition I'm stuggling to apply it and spot $a + bi$ and wondered if I should take $a=4+n$ and $b=6n$

Yes. So, $|4+n+6in|^2=(4+n)^2+(6n)^2\le(4n+n)^2+(6n)^2=61n^2$ hence $\left| z_n - \frac12 \right|\le\frac{\sqrt{61}n}{2n^2-n}.$

Oops $\left| z_n - \frac12 \right|\le\frac{\sqrt{61}n}{4n^2-2n}\le\frac{\sqrt{61}n}{2n^2}.$

Your first $\overset{?}=$ should be:
$$\left|\frac{4 + n + 6in}{4n^2 - 2n} \right|
=\frac{\sqrt{(4+n)^2+36n^2}}{4n^2 - 2n}
<\frac{4+7n}{4n^2-2n}.$$
Follw your proof: when $n>8$, we have
$$\left|\frac{4+n+6in}{4n^2-2n}\right|
\leq\frac{4+7n}{4n^2-2n}<\frac{8n-4}{4n^2-2n}=\frac{2}{n}<\epsilon.$$
Here I just use the "tricky"(@Anne Bauval says) Triangle Inequality:
$$|z_1+z_2|\leq |z_1|+|z_2|,$$
with $z_1=4+n$ and $z_2=6n\text{i}$, we can get
$$|4+n+6n\text{i}|<4+n+6n=4+7n.$$

Yes, I just want to know why? I don't  blame anyone!

I didn't downvote, but it could be related to this.

There were 2 downvotes. I just retracted mine because you improved your answer, eventually addressing the OP's main problem. Still, I find your upperbound too tricky (compare with mine in comments above).

@Anne Bauval It is just the Triangle Inequality：$ |z_1+z_2|≤|z_1|+|z_2|$
．I don't know why you think it is "tricky"?

Now it is clearer. At first, $\frac{\sqrt{(4+n)^2+36n^2}}{4n^2 - 2n}
<\frac{4+7n}{4n^2-2n}$ came out of the blue ($4+7n<8n-4$ for $n>8$ still does).  I suggest you reorganize all this.
